# MySQL + Python : Wrong number of arguments during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql

I am executing below query in python to insert data:

```
  query = "INSERT INTO tweetMelbourne(created_at,geo_coordinates_latitude,geo_coordinates_longitude,user_id,polarity_score)" \
                "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
        args = (created_at,geo_coordinates_latitude,geo_coordinates_longitude,user_id,polarity_score)

        try:        
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query, args)
```

> But its giving error: Wrong number of arguments during string
>   formatting

My MySQL table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tweetMelbourne (
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    `geo_coordinates_latitude` decimal(12,9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `geo_coordinates_longitude` decimal(12,9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id` INT,
    `polarity_score` INT
)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Lat and long are FLOAT not INT

Comment: So what should I use for float online they are using %s for all

Comment: Use %s for Integer cell ?